# Links with data-remote not firing correctly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, unobtrusive-javascript

I just switched to jQuery from Prototype in my Rails 3 application. I used the latest Rails.js file for jQuery and v1.4.4 of the core jQuery library. My AJAX forms seem to be working fine, and otherwise things were behaving properly (including my Delete links). The one problem I'm having is with:
`link_to "Some Page", page_path, :remote => true`

Nothing seems to happen when I click my links, but the logs show a successful, regular 'GET' cycle completing in the background. All the layouts render (which shouldn't) and all the normal processing takes place. I can't seem to get the damn thing to act remotely. What am I doing wrong?

Excerpt from the beginning of my log file:

```
Started GET "/reservations?show=all" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-12-25 16:08:08 -0500
  Processing by ReservationsController#index as */*
  Parameters: {"show"=>"all"}
```

Any suggestions would be very helpful...

Update RE @noodl (1.13.2011):
I have an index.js file that does some updating on the page. I have "View All" "View Recent" "View Completed", etc links on the page that filter the index of Reservations. All of this was being handled and working with Prototype. Once I switched to jQuery, nothing seems to happen, and I can't figure out why. This is 3 weeks old now and I still haven't figured it out. Not a high priority (obviously), but still a weird behavior. I'll keep investigating and post a response if I figure anything out.

Comment: Is the `index` action getting called?

Comment: It is. The server processes the `index` method in the controller, runs through the entire process and 'renders' all the partials and layouts, including `index.html.erb`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what it is you think *should* happen. You're making an XHR GET request for a page and then doing nothing with the response.

If you mean for the response to be inserted in to the page somewhere, it's up to you to catch the response via a callback in your javascript. If you mean simply to go to the specified link, why use `:remote => true`?

*Confused*.

Comment: Sorry @noodl, I should have been clearer. I *am* doing something with my response. Something that once worked but didn't after I updated to use jQuery instead of Prototype. I'll edit my response above...